# vim syntax highlighting for jinja2?

Tags: python, vim, jinja2, vim-syntax-highlighting

How do you do jinja2 aware syntax highlighting for vim?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There appears to be a syntax highlighting file [here](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1856).

Comment: Easy as adding `Plugin 'Glench/Vim-Jinja2-Syntax'`